# Tela de login agindo de forma incoerente

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Montei uma tela de login onde o usuario deve colocar login e senha com o codigo abaixo:

```
procedure TFMLogin.Img_confClick(Sender: TObject);
var verif: boolean;
begin
 FMHome.ADOLogin.SQL.add('Select * from "login" where "usuario" = :usuario AND "senha" = :senha');
  FMHome.ADOLogin.Parameters.ParamByName('usuario').Value := edt_usuario.Text;
  FMHome.ADOLogin.Parameters.ParamByName('senha').Value := edt_senha.Text;
  FMHome.ADOLogin.Open;
  try
    if Not (FMHome.ADOLogin.isEmpty) then
    begin
      Modalresult := mrok;
      verif := true;
    end
    else
    begin
      Application.MessageBox('Senha ou usuário incorretos!','Atenção',MB_OK+MB_ICONINFORMATION);
      edt_usuario.Clear;
      edt_senha.Clear;
      edt_usuario.SetFocus;
      verif := False;
    end;
  finally
    FMHome.ADOLogin.Close;

  end;
    if (verif = true) then
  begin
      FreeAndNil(FmLogin); //Libera o form de Login da memória
      Application.CreateForm(TFmHome, FmHome); //Cria a janela main
      Application.Run; //Roda a aplicação
  end;
end;
```

para criar um novo usuario caso a pessoa não tenha o login senha é o seguinte:

```
procedure TFMLogin.lbl_cadastroClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
UDM.ADODSLogin.open;
UDM.ADODSLogin.Insert;
FMCad_Login.showmodal;
end;
```

após preencher os campos o passo é confirmar:

```
procedure TFMCad_Login.Img_confClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
UDM.ADODSLogin.Post;
end;
```

Tabela Login:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Nesse momento, o registro vai para o banco de dados

porem eu tenho 3 usuarios cadastrados, e só consigo entrar com o ultimo que foi inserido e após um tempo só consigo acessar com o de ID n° 1

Aonde estou errando?

Comment: tem como mostrar a estrutura da tabela login ?

Comment: adicionei a perguntaq

Comment: da algum erro ou simplesmente não loga ?

Comment: nao loga, da a mensagem que coloquei de senha ou usuario incorreto

Comment: abre a base de dados e tira um "print" e mostra os dados como estão na base, se possivel de detalhes da tabela, tipo dos campos etc, id, chave primaria!

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Ok, se os dados estão gravados corretamente, vamos mudar isso aqui e vê se acontece algo:  FMHome.ADOLogin.SQL.add('Select * from login where usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha'); Retire as aspas duplas!

Comment: negativo, com as outras senhas nao funcionam, a que está com ID_login 1 funciona.

Comment: da um Truncate nessa tabela e cadastra 1 novo usuário! Depois cadastre outro usuário diferente

Comment: tem algo errado, se eu colocar qualquer coisa no campo de login e a senha correta, ele entra no sistema

Comment: FMHome.ADOLogin.SQL.add('Select FIRST 1 * FROM login where usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha'), acabei de testar aqui, este funciona tambem

Comment: continua da mesma forma...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, Adicione na sua Tabela um novo campo `login` e ao invés de usar o `usuario` como Login vamos usar `login` como Login, agora cadastre 3 novos usuários:

**Editado:** Na sua tabela, coloque o novo campo `login` como chave primária!

```
------------------------------------
usuario         - login   - senha
------------------------------------
joao santos     - jsantos - j48f2
marcos pereira  - marpere - mgn30ds
maria aparecida - mariaap - nm4n9dn
------------------------------------
```

Vamos mudar:

`FMHome.ADOLogin.SQL.add('Select * from login where usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha');`

Para

```
FMHome.ADOLogin.SQL.add('Select usuario from login where usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha');
```

Agora após o .Open:

```
Application.MessageBox(FMHome.ADOLogin.FieldByName('usuario').AsString,'Usuário Logado',MB_OK+MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Comment: Um importante adicional na resposta!

Answer (score 0):

no seguinte procedimento:

```
procedure TFMLogin.lbl_cadastroClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   UDM.ADODSLogin.open;
   UDM.ADODSLogin.Insert;
   FMCad_Login.showmodal;
end;
```

verifique se o SQL do seu ADODSLogin esta com ou sem o where, se estiver com o where melhor retirar o mesmo deixar somente:

```
select * from Login
```

e não sei se altera algo, porem prefiro sempre trabalhar com `append` no lugar do `insert`.

Como dica ate para tentar resolver o problema ou alguem conseguir te ajudar.
Quando incluir e acessar o sistema com o novo usuario veja como ficou a tabela do seu banco de dados, se ele incluiu ou nao o registro e se esta salvo da forma correta.

Espero ter ajudado.