# Como logar sistema no delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Sou novato em Delphi e reparei que não há a presença de uso de variáveis como data `readers` nesse linguagem como no VB. Estou fazendo um `procedure` para logar no sistema. A conexão com o banco já esta pronta e funcional minha duvida é:

Como prosseguir com a leitura de dados no banco agora?

Segue código com a conexão com o banco:

```
procedure TFrmPrincipal.GetConnection();
var
  diretorioDb: String;
begin
  diretorioDb := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));

  if FileExists(diretorioDb + 'DataBase.mdb') then
  begin
    if dmDados.bdConnection.Connected = false then
    begin
      dmDados.bdConnection.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Psddword="";Data Source=' + diretorioDb + 'DataBase.mdbde Seu programa';
      dbDados.bdConnection.Connected        := true;
    end
    else
    begin
      dmDados.bdConnection.Connected := false;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Banco de Dados não Encontrado!');
  end;
end;
```

Método de login:

```
procedure TfrmLogin.LogarSistema(userPr: string; senhaPr: string);
begin
  with dmDados.query do
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username =userPr and senha =senhaPr');

    Parameters.ParamByName('userPr').Value  := userPr;
    Parameters.ParamByName('senhaPr').Value := senhaPr;

    ExecSQL;
  end;
  showmessage('Logado Com Sucesso!');
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após o ExecSQL você deve verificar se existe dados conforme passados por parâmetro:

```
if (dmDados.IsEmpty = False) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Logado com Sucesso');
end
else
begin
  ShowMessage('Senha incorreta, ou usuário inexistente');
end;
```

De toda forma, eu ja respondi uma pergunta a tempos atras que pode lhe ajudar:

[Tela de login agindo de forma incoerente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100770/tela-de-login-agindo-de-forma-incoerente)

Comment: ExecSql não abre o dataset, apenas executa a intrução. No caso, deveria ser dmDados.query.open. Depois, é só testar se o dataset não está vazio (dmDados.query.IsEmpty).

Comment: observe que ele utilisa `with dmDados.query do` então apenas o `IsEmpty `é necessário...